# Outlook modify and Save() MailItems - slow

Tags: performance, outlook, vsto, outlook-2007, outlook-addin

I need to modify many MailItems in Outlook 2007.

I need the mails to immediately refresh in the main Outlook grid - the only way to do this I found is to call MailItem.Save().

```
foreach (var item in folder.Items)
{
    var mail = item as MailItem;
    if (mail != null)     // process only MailItems
    {
        setUserProperty(mail, userPropKey, "speed test");  
        mail.Save();      // Save() to make the grid row redraw
        if (++cnt == 10)  // stop after 10 mails
            break;
    }
}
```

The problem is that **Save() is slow on IMAP account** - 1s per 1 Save() call, probably due to communication with server. On POP3 account it is ok.

The modification I need to make on every email is just changing a User property. I have a custom View defined in Outlook that shows a column with this property.

Is there a way to:

- make the user property local to PST, so that no communication with server  is done on Save() ?
- do all the Save() calls in one batch ?

I'm setting user property on emails like this:

```
void setUserProperty(Outlook.MailItem item, string key, string value)
{
     item.UserProperties.Add(key, Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText, true, Outlook.OlFormatText.olFormatTextText);
     item.UserProperties[key].Value = value;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the imap cached mode?

Comment: And no, all save()s in a batch is not possible - the outlook object model (COM) is in a single threaded apartment and save() seems to be synchronous.

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely look at IMAP cached mode. On Exchange, luckily, Save() is fast too, so the only problem is IMAP.

Comment: Did that solve it? Just curious myself.

Comment: Hi, finally got to it (lot of work, sorry). I have found information about Exchange cached mode, but no information about using "cached mode" for standart IMAP (eg. gmail) accout - haven't found out how to turn cached mode on yet.. Is it possible?

Comment: Even better would be to tell Outlook not to send anything to server on Save() when only user properties changed, but I'm afraid that's not possible.

Comment: It should at least be possible to activate cached mode for IMAP accounts when creating a new one (from what i've read, haven't tried it). Otherwise the problem with Save() is by design.

Comment: Another thing: try asking at microsoft.public.office.developer.com.add_ins, maybe people like Ken Slovak have an idea for an alternative approach: http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.office.developer.com.add_ins/topics